# Bash: rename duplicates for generated values in csv file

Tags: bash, csv, if-statement, while-loop

There is a bash script that create a email addresses in next format: first letter from name and full surname, lowercase +@example.com.

csv file:

```
id,location,name,email
1,1,John Smith,ab@dc.com
2,2,Paul Robinson,
3,3,Fidel Guererro,qw@er.com
4,4,John Smith,
...
```

Column *Name* can contain duplicates. In this case script should add 1 in email address (*ex. for id=1 - jsmith@example.com, for id=4  - jsmith1@example.com*).
I try next script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 col3 col4
do
            if [ "$col1" == Id ]; then
                echo "${col1},${col2},${col3},${col4}"
                continue
            fi

    firstinitial=${col3:0:1}
    surname=$(echo $col3 | cut -d' ' -f2)

            if [[ $col4 ==  $col4 ]]; then
                col4=${firstinitial,}${surname,,}1@example.com
                else
                col4=${firstinitial,}${surname,,}@example.com
            fi

    echo "${col1},${col2},${col3},${col4}"
done < acc.csv
```

I recieve all addresses with 1.
How can I change  this script?

Expected output:

```
id,location,name,email
1,1,John Smith,jsmith@example.com
2,2,Paul Robinson,probinson@example.com
3,3,Fidel Guererro,fguererro@example.com
4,4,John Smith,jsmith1@example.com
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and special thanks for showing your efforts, could you please do add sample of input and expected output more clearly in your question and let us know. That will help us to understand your question more clearly.

Comment: @diz : You don't check for duplicates in your code. You just compare col4 (email) to itself (col4 (email)) in the input data. Like in mathematics, `x==x` is always true. Also, what should happen if you find several duplicates? Should all the following ones get the number 1 added?

Comment: Added expected output. If script finds duplicates, should add 1 to the next one address.

Comment: an aside - not all names are "first/last". To check dups, try an associative array lookup table.